# Strange HealthKit Access issue

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm working on retrieving steps data within HealthKit. The query all works as expected (I'm only retrieving step data) however I'm having a strange issue with the Health Access modal that appears (see screenshot below - this is NOT my app, just an example screenshot taken from the web)

[image]

The issue is when the user soft closes the app (i.e. pressing the home to get to springboard) and then goes back into the app. The modal doesn't want to disappear when clicking allow or disallow.

Looking at the log it appears I have this strange error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=5 "(null)"
```

Any thoughts? If further info is required please let me know.

P.S. Just an addition to this, I notice that when clicking "Don't Allow" (where the "Cancel" is within the screenshot), I get an alert dialogue stating:

> "You can turn on health data categories later in the Health app."

Upon clicking "OK" the Health Access screen still does not dismiss.

P.S.S. Not sure if this affect this but when the Health Access screen appears, it does so with the following message in the Log:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x1343f4040>.
```

Comment: This appears to happen too within the ResearchKit Sample app... https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/tree/master/samples/ORKSample

Comment: Odd - sounds like a bug; a modal dialog should be dismissable. You can report it to Apple at: https://bugreport.apple.com